# pkgdown builds in Ubuntu but not Windows: argument `str` should be a character vector

Tags: r, windows, ubuntu, package, stringi

I've asked [this similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45870948/error-in-stri-split-boundaries-argument-str-should-be-a-character-vector) question before. I've done more digging and made this question as minimal and reproducible as possible:

First I created a new package [as described here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/package.html#getting-started) and built a site with `pkgdown`. This builds a site as expected:

```
pkgdown::build_site()
Initialising site ------------------------------------------------------------------
Copying 'C:/Users/name/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/pkgdown/assets/jquery.sticky-kit.min.js'
Copying 'C:/Users/name/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/pkgdown/assets/link.svg'
Copying 'C:/Users/name/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/pkgdown/assets/pkgdown.css'
Copying 'C:/Users/name/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/pkgdown/assets/pkgdown.js'
Building home ----------------------------------------------------------------------
Writing 'C:\Users\name\Dropbox\Rpackages\runchart-11-debugging-pkgdown\runchart\docs/authors.html'
Writing 'C:\Users\name\Dropbox\Rpackages\runchart-11-debugging-pkgdown\runchart\docs/index.html'
Building function reference --------------------------------------------------------
Creating 'C:\Users\name\Dropbox\Rpackages\runchart-11-debugging-pkgdown\runchart\docs/reference/'
Loading runchart
Writing 'C:\Users\name\Dropbox\Rpackages\runchart-11-debugging-pkgdown\runchart\docs/reference/index.html'
Processing hello.Rd
Writing 'C:\Users\name\Dropbox\Rpackages\runchart-11-debugging-pkgdown\runchart\docs/reference/hello.html'
```

But if I create a default vignette - the site no longer builds:

```
> devtools::use_vignette("my-vignette")
* Creating `vignettes`.
* Adding `inst/doc` to ./.gitignore
> pkgdown::build_site()
Initialising site ------------------------------------------------------------------
Copying 'C:/Users/name/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/pkgdown/assets/jquery.sticky-kit.min.js'
Copying 'C:/Users/name/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/pkgdown/assets/link.svg'
Copying 'C:/Users/name/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/pkgdown/assets/pkgdown.css'
Copying 'C:/Users/name/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/pkgdown/assets/pkgdown.js'
Building home ----------------------------------------------------------------------
Writing 'C:\Users\name\Dropbox\Rpackages\runchart-11-debugging-pkgdown\runchart\docs/authors.html'
Writing 'C:\Users\name\Dropbox\Rpackages\runchart-11-debugging-pkgdown\runchart\docs/index.html'
Building function reference --------------------------------------------------------
Loading runchart
Writing 'C:\Users\name\Dropbox\Rpackages\runchart-11-debugging-pkgdown\runchart\docs/reference/index.html'
Processing hello.Rd
Writing 'C:\Users\name\Dropbox\Rpackages\runchart-11-debugging-pkgdown\runchart\docs/reference/hello.html'
Building articles ------------------------------------------------------------------
Creating 'C:\Users\name\Dropbox\Rpackages\runchart-11-debugging-pkgdown\runchart\docs/articles/'
Building article 'my-vignette.html'
Error in stri_split_boundaries(string, n = n, simplify = simplify, opts_brkiter = opts(pattern)) : 
  argument `str` should be a character vector (or an object coercible to)
```

Here's the traceback:

```
> traceback()
8: stop(err[[2]])
7: get_result(output = out, options)
6: callr::r_safe(function(...) rmarkdown::render(...), args = list(input, 
       output_format = format$format, output_file = basename(output_file), 
       quiet = quiet, encoding = encoding, envir = globalenv()), 
       show = !quiet)
5: .f(input = "C:\\Users\\name\\Dropbox\\Rpackages\\runchart-11-debugging-pkgdown\\runchart\\docs/articles/my-vignette.Rmd", 
       output_file = "my-vignette.html", depth = 1L, pkg = list(
           package = "runchart", path = ".", desc = <environment>, 
           meta = list(), topics = list(name = "hello", file_in = "hello.Rd", 
               file_out = "hello.html", alias = list(hello.Rd = "hello"), 
               usage = list(hello.Rd = list(hello())), funs = list(
                   hello.Rd = "hello"), title = "Hello, World!", 
               rd = list(hello.Rd = list(list("hello"), "\n", list(
                   "hello"), "\n", list("Hello, World!"), "\n", 
                   list("\n", "hello()\n"), "\n", list("\n", "Prints 'Hello, world!'.\n"), 
                   "\n", list("\n", "hello()\n"), "\n")), concepts = list(
                   hello.Rd = character(0)), internal = FALSE), 
           vignettes = list(file_in = "my-vignette.Rmd", file_out = "my-vignette.html", 
               name = "my-vignette", path = ".", vig_depth = 0L, 
               title = "Vignette Title"), topic_index = "hello", 
           article_index = "my-vignette.html"), data = list(pagetitle = "$title$"), 
       encoding = "UTF-8", quiet = TRUE)
4: do.call(".f", c(args, list(...)))
3: purrr::pwalk(articles, render_rmd, pkg = pkg, data = data, encoding = encoding, 
       quiet = quiet)
2: build_articles(pkg, path = file.path(path, "articles"), depth = 1L, 
       encoding = encoding)
1: pkgdown::build_site()
```

I've tried these same steps on Ubuntu (hello world package with hello world vignette) and `pkgdown` builds a site without issue.

session info for Windows (which doesn't build):

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.5.0    stringr_1.1.0  runchart_0.2.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.9        whisker_0.3-2      knitr_1.15.1       xml2_1.1.1         magrittr_1.5       roxygen2_6.0.1    
 [7] MASS_7.3-45        pkgload_0.0.0.9000 debugme_1.0.2      R6_2.2.2           rlang_0.1.2.9000   httr_1.3.1        
[13] tools_3.3.2        DBI_0.5-1          withr_2.0.0        htmltools_0.3.5    commonmark_1.2     yaml_2.1.14       
[19] assertthat_0.1     digest_0.6.12      rprojroot_1.2      tibble_1.3.3       pkgdown_0.1.0.9000 crayon_1.3.2      
[25] processx_2.0.0.1   callr_1.0.0.9000   purrr_0.2.3        curl_2.3           memoise_1.1.0      evaluate_0.10.1   
[31] rmarkdown_1.6      stringi_1.1.2      desc_1.1.1         backports_1.0.5
```

session info for Ubuntu (which does build):

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] runchart_0.1.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.12        compiler_3.4.1      git2r_0.19.0        tools_3.4.1        
 [5] highlight_0.4.7.1   digest_0.6.12       pkgbuild_0.0.0.9000 pkgload_0.0.0.9000 
 [9] memoise_1.1.0       evaluate_0.10.1     tibble_1.3.4        rlang_0.1.2        
[13] rstudioapi_0.7      commonmark_1.4      curl_2.8.1          yaml_2.1.14        
[17] pkgdown_0.1.0.9000  withr_2.0.0         httr_1.3.1          stringr_1.2.0      
[21] roxygen2_6.0.1      xml2_1.1.1          knitr_1.17          desc_1.1.1         
[25] devtools_1.13.3     rprojroot_1.2       R6_2.2.2            rmarkdown_1.6      
[29] callr_1.0.0         purrr_0.2.3         magrittr_1.5        whisker_0.3-2      
[33] backports_1.1.0     clisymbols_1.2.0    htmltools_0.3.6     MASS_7.3-47        
[37] usethis_0.1.0       assertthat_0.2.0    stringi_1.1.5       crayon_1.3.4
```

Comment: It looks like some of your windows packages are older. Maybe try updating first?

Comment: That was it - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pkgdown [imports Rmarkdown](https://github.com/hadley/pkgdown/blob/master/DESCRIPTION) which [imports stringr (>= 1.2.0)](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/DESCRIPTION).

I updated stringr on Windows from 1.1.0 to 1.2.0 and the site now builds.